# Trouble on SearchBar loading plist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am loading my plist into a TableView and it is going everything ok, but now I am trying to include a SearchBar on the Page1. Below you see the directory.plist and my Main.storyboard

[image: plist and storyboard]

To load the plist correctly I put the following code on my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "directory", withExtension: "plist"), let array = NSArray(contentsOf: url) as? [[String:Any]] {
            Shared.instance.employees = array.map{Employee(dictionary: $0)}
        }
        return true
}
```

I also have a Structure helping me to load all my stuff:

```
struct EmployeeDetails {
    let functionary: String
    let imageFace: String
    let phone: String

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.functionary = (dictionary["Functionary"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.imageFace = (dictionary["ImageFace"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.phone = (dictionary["Phone"] as? String) ?? ""
    }
}
struct Employee {
    let position: String
    let name: String
    let details: [EmployeeDetails] // [String:Any]

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.position = (dictionary["Position"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.name = (dictionary["Name"] as? String) ?? ""

        let t = (dictionary["Details"] as? [Any]) ?? []
        self.details = t.map({EmployeeDetails(dictionary: $0 as! [String : Any])})
    }
}

struct Shared {
    static var instance = Shared()
    var employees: [Employee] = []
}
```

**Until here, everything is running well!** Now I became having trouble when I tried to insert a SearchView, take a look what I did until now:

```
class Page1: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    let employeesSearching: [String] = [String]()  //now using: var employeesSearching = [Employee]()
    var isSearching : Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.isSearching == true {
            return self.employeesSearching.count
        } else {
            return Shared.instance.employees.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1
        let employee = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]

        if self.isSearching == true {
            cell.nameLabel.text = self.employeesSearching[indexPath.row].name
            cell.positionLabel.text = self.employeesSearching[indexPath.row].position
        } else {
            cell.nameLabel.text = employee.name
            cell.positionLabel.text = employee.position
        }
        return cell
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if self.searchBar.text!.isEmpty {
            self.isSearching = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            self.isSearching = true
            self.employeesSearching.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            for i in 0..<self.Shared.instance.itens.count {
                let listItem : String = self.Shared.instance.itens[i]
                if listItem.lowercased().range(of: self.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) != nil {
                    self.employeesSearching.append(listItem)
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? Page2,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destination.newPage = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

These are the exactly mistakes:
[image]

---

**EDIT 1**
After tips, now the only trouble is:
[image]

---

**EDIT 2**
Now I am having this:
[image]

Comment: I rolled back your last change since it is about a completely different issue. Post a new question if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are because `employeesSearching` is a constant array of `String`.

You probably want a variable array of `Employee`.

Change:

```
let employeesSearching: [String] = [String]()
```

to:

```
var employeesSearching = [Employee]()
```

Comment: Nice!! Now I have one last trouble, I just updated the question to show you. One last line wrong.

Comment: You should not redo your question like that. It makes my answer seem inappropriate. If anything, add the new image to show the additional error. But you probably want `Shared.instance.employees.count` instead of `self.Shared.instance.items.count`.

Comment: I redid my question like before … It a kinda worked, but other troubles appeared. On line 58 (`Value of type 'Page1' has no member 'Shared'`), when I remove `self.` I see: (`Cannot convert value of type 'Employee' to specified type 'String'`) and on line 60 (`Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Employee'`)

Comment: You need to fix line 58 like you did for 57. And the list of employees isn't a `String`, it's an `Employee`.

Comment: Great! I made it, just added the result to my question. One last problem on line 59… WTF is `lowercased()`? lol

Comment: Look at the documentation for `String`. You probably want to call `lowercased()` on `listItem.name`.

Comment: App is running right, but the search is a kind weird…

Comment: That would be a topic for a whole new question if needed. This question has been answered and solved. You should close this question by accepting my answer if you feel it solved your original issue.

Comment: That's true, all problems here were solved! Thanks again buddy!